# bash_profile and svn

Tags: unix, svn, .bash-profile

I'm a bit new to the Unix environment and am having trouble with my bash_profile and svn. Basically my bash_profile only contains information about coloring the terminal. However, when I make the bash_profile, it messes up my svn installation. Do I need to specify a PATH or something in the bash_profile? Is there a list of things you need or should include in the bash_profile?

Here's my current bash profile:

```
alias ls="ls -G"
export LSCOLORS='gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad'

PS1="[\!][\[\e[0;32m\]\t\[\e[0m\]][\[\e[0;36m\]\w\[\e[0m\]]\$ "

alias l="ls -G"
alias o=open
alias grep='egrep --colour=always'
```

(also, I'm running Mac OSX 10.8.2 in case that matters)

Comment: @alextehbake, it would help a lot if you could add the contents of your bash_profile file to your question.

Comment: yea sorry about that. I put it in now

Comment: What leads you to believe that the .bash_profile is messing with svn? Did svn work before adding that file and then no longer works once it is sourced? Can you reproduce this? What happens if you remove the .bash_profile?

Comment: It works before I make the bash_profile, then stops working once i've set it up, then continues to work when I remove it. I've also done it multiple times with the same result. Maybe it's something else, but that's the only thing I can think of

Comment: "It works" and "stops working" aren't terrible descriptive. Can you add some more color? What do you see with and without the .bash_profile when you type what command?

Comment: I mean that svn works when I don't have the .bash_profile and it stops working when I do have it. However, the colors do work when I have the bash_profile

Comment: When you say "it stops working", does it do nothing? return an error message? do something, but not what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have either `.bash_login` or `.profile` in your home directory. Your `bash` may have been executing svn-related setup in one of these files, which it will no longer do if you create `.bash_profile`. `bash` only executes the first of `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, or `.profile` (in that order) that it finds.